# Starting a Spring Boot Applications with SSL connection, Mysql in IntellIJ, and a veu Application using docker compose

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I'm trying to run my services with a Docker compose on MacBook Air M2, I launch three containers that are connected to each other per ports, When I run the application locally (not with Docker), it seems to work fine. Only I start Docker compose, I get an error with backend container, the other two containers (mysql and frontend are Ok), I'm new to Docker and Spring Boot, any suggestions?

Note: port 8443 is available on my machine and there are no other service using it...

this is Dockerfile of backend service

```
# Stage 1: Build the application
FROM maven:3.8.4-openjdk-11 AS build
WORKDIR /app



COPY ./devops_bht_ss23_backend/ /app
RUN mvn clean package -DskipTests

# Stage 2: Create the runtime image
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/target/spring-boot-jwt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar .
# RUN sh -c 'touch spring-boot-jwt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'


EXPOSE 8443
CMD ["java", "-jar", "spring-boot-jwt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

here is my application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://db:3306/mylist?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = ****

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
jwt.secret = WHENTOD******

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL = DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type = TRACE
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true

spring.mail.host = smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port = 587
spring.mail.username = ****8@gmail.com
spring.mail.password = *****
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.timeout = 30000

server.port = 8443
server.ssl.enabled = true
server.ssl.key-store = src/main/resources/bootsecurity.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password = bootsecuritypassword
server.ssl.key-store-type = PKCS12
server.ssl.key-alias = bootsecurity
```

here is Docker Compose File with the three services:

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./devops_bht_ss23_backend/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8443:8443
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
       spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/mylist?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
       spring.datasource.username: root
       spring.datasource.password: *****
       spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
       spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update
       jwt.secret: WHENTODOLISTISCOOL
       logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG
       logging.level.org.hibernate.type: TRACE
       spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql: true

       spring.mail.host: smtp.gmail.com
       spring.mail.port: 587
       spring.mail.username: *****@gmail.com
       spring.mail.password: *****
       spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth: true
       spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable: true
       spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required: true
       spring.mail.properties.mail.timeout: 30000
       server.port: 8443
       server.ssl.enabled: true
       server.ssl.key-store: src/main/resources/bootsecurity.p12
       server.ssl.key-store-password: bootsecuritypassword
       server.ssl.key-store-type: PKCS12
       server.ssl.key-alias: bootsecurity
       DEBUG: true



    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql

  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mylist
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: *****
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./devops_bht_ss23_frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - backend

volumes:
  mysql_data:
```

here is my project structure from backend project:
[backend structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ipa4w.png)

and here a part of log output:

```
2023-08-10 16:38:38 2023-08-10 14:38:38.824 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : Application failed to start due to an exception
2023-08-10 16:38:38 
2023-08-10 16:38:38 org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.ConnectorStartFailedException: Connector configured to listen on port 8443 failed to start
2023-08-10 16:38:38     at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.checkConnectorHasStarted(TomcatWebServer.java:232) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
2023-08-10 16:38:38     at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.checkThatConnectorsHaveStarted(TomcatWebServer.java:224) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
2023-08-10 16:38:38     at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:202) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
2023-08-10 16:38:38     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:311) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
2023-08-10 16:38:38     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
2023-08-10 16:38:38     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
2023-08-10 16:38:38     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
2023-08-10 16:38:38     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
2023-08-10 16:38:38     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
2023-08-10 16:38:38     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
2023-08-10 16:38:38     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
2023-08-10 16:38:38     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
2023-08-10 16:38:38     at com.todolist.Application.main(Application.java:17) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2023-08-10 16:38:38     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
2023-08-10 16:38:38     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2023-08-10 16:38:38     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2023-08-10 16:38:38     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2023-08-10 16:38:38     at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[spring-boot-jwt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2023-08-10 16:38:38     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[spring-boot-jwt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2023-08-10 16:38:38     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-jwt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2023-08-10 16:38:38     at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) ~[spring-boot-jwt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2023-08-10 16:38:38 
2023-08-10 16:38:38 2023-08-10 14:38:38.825 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 
2023-08-10 16:38:38 
2023-08-10 16:38:38 ***************************
2023-08-10 16:38:38 APPLICATION FAILED TO START
2023-08-10 16:38:38 ***************************
2023-08-10 16:38:38 
2023-08-10 16:38:38 Description:
2023-08-10 16:38:38 
2023-08-10 16:38:38 The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8443 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.
2023-08-10 16:38:38 
2023-08-10 16:38:38 Action:
2023-08-10 16:38:38 
2023-08-10 16:38:38 Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8443, or configure this application to listen on another port.
2023-08-10 16:38:38 
2023-08-10 16:38:38 2023-08-10 14:38:38.825 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@76f2b07d, started on Thu Aug 10 14:38:36 UTC 2023
2023-08-10 16:38:38 2023-08-10 14:38:38.828  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2023-08-10 16:38:38 2023-08-10 14:38:38.829  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-08-10 16:38:38 2023-08-10 14:38:38.829 TRACE 1 --- [           main] o.h.type.spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope     : Handling #sessionFactoryClosed from [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@5fad41be] for TypeConfiguration
2023-08-10 16:38:38 2023-08-10 14:38:38.829 DEBUG 1 --- [           main] o.h.type.spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope     : Un-scoping TypeConfiguration [org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope@70d77826] from SessionFactory [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@5fad41be]
2023-08-10 16:38:38 2023-08-10 14:38:38.830  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-08-10 16:38:38 2023-08-10 14:38:38.842  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```